# Solve this limit

Tags: limits

Given that

$$f(5x)=8x-f(3x)-\sin^2(2x),$$

find

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } \frac { f\left( x \right) -x }{ x^2 } =?\quad $$  Instead of putting f(x) I put f(5x) now i think it would be easier ?

Comment: No that's f(x) not f(5x)

Comment: Why did you repost the question? That is strictly against the rules.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, the OP went back and forth at the other question between $f(x)$ and $f(5x)$ on the LHS (attracting answers to each version).  It's currently back to $f(x)$ there, so this is technically a different question.

Comment: I didn't repost it, first it was f(x) then I instead of post another question I edited the first question and now every thing is okay I cancelled that edit @Jakrilahtonen thank you

Comment: @BarryCipra thank you :) , can you solve the question above ?

Comment: @SuheirAlSabbah, the problem is, both versions attracted answers.  It's OK to change a problem if it hasn't attracted any answers (the best course is to delete, edit, and undelete, if you need an appreciable amount of time to make the edit), but if it has, it's better to post a new question, with a link to the old one and an explanation of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate the given equation $0,1,2$ times, and let $x=0$. Then solve for $f(0),f'(0),f''(0)$ which yields $(0,1,-4/17)$

Replace $f$ by its 2nd degree taylor expansion at $x=0$ (higher order terms are killed by the denominator)
$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } \frac { f\left( x \right) -x }{ x^2 } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } \frac { \frac{1}{2} x^2 f''(0)+x f'(0)+f(0) -x }{ x^2 } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 } \frac { \frac{1}{2} x^2 f''(0) }{ x^2 } =-2/17 $$

Comment: I didn't understand? Can you explain and solve all of it please ?

Comment: @SuheirAlSabbah To differentiate the equation you need to know the chain rule